# Перенос переменной из JavaScript в HTML

Tags: javascript, html

Имеется следующий код:

```js
success:function(response){
                var as = 3+4;
                document.getElementById("mesto").innerHTML = as;
                
                row = $("<tr></tr>");
                col1 = $("<td hidden>col1</td>");
                col2 = $("<td></td>");
                col3 = $("<td>col3</td>");
                col4 = $("<td>col3</td>");
                col5 = $("<td>col3</td>");
                col6 = $("<td>col3</td>");
                col7 = $("<td>col3</td>");
                col8 = $("<td>col3</td>");
                col9 = $("<td>col3</td>");
                col10 = $("<td hidden>col3</td>");
                row.append(col1,col2,col3,col4,col5,col6,col7,col8,col9,col10).prependTo("#myTable");
              },
```

В каждую из ячеек нужно вставить переменную из JS (привёл лишь кусок кода с формированием таблицы). Если использовать innerHTML, то скрипт не обрабатывается, так как похоже находится в success:function. Есть ли какие-то другие способы это сделать?

Comment: Я ничего не понял.

Comment: **Зачем** вы мешаете jQuery с Javascript?

Answer (score 0):

На самом деле не надо ничего выдумывать такое изощрённое. Формируете html и вставляете в нужное место. Примерно так:

```
let data = { ... }
let tableHTML = `
    <tr>
        <td>${data['id']}</td>
        <td>${data['name']}</td>
        <td>${data['age']}</td>
    </tr>
`;
$("#myTable").html(tableHTML);
```

где ``  - это синтаксис шаблоннных строк, и `${data['id']}` переменные, которые можно вставлять в шаблонные строки

Comment: в jQuery все-таки [`.html`](https://api.jquery.com/html/) метод называется

Comment: @Grundy точно, спасибо. Что-то меня коротнуло)